# iOS app saved data lost after updating

Tags: ios, xamarin, hockeyapp

I have an iPhone app that I developed with Xamarin and am publishing on HockeyApp. Whenever I put a new version of the app on HockeyApp and someone updates their current installation on their phone, they lose the saved data. Is there any way to prevent this?

**EDIT**

I have an entitlement that let's me share the data with my widget too. Could that be the problem? This is how I'm writing/reading the data:

```
this.nsUserDefaults = new NSUserDefaults("myGroupId", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);

// Write data:
this.nsUserDefaults.SetString("myValue", "myKey");
this.nsUserDefaults.Synchronize();

// Read data:
string myValue = this.nsUserDefaults.StringForKey("myKey");
```

**EDIT**

After changing the above code to the following, it now persists saved data after updating:

```
// Write data:
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("myValue", "myKey");
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
// Read data:
string myValue = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("myKey");
```

But now I won't be able to share data with my widget...how can I solve this while still being able to share the data with my widget?

Comment: How your app saves data? `NSUserDefaults`, Keychain, CoreData?

Comment: NSUserDefaults.

Comment: does the data persist between different launches of the app? Also share some details on what kind of data you are saving?

Comment: Yes it does persist between different launches of the app.

Comment: I changed the way I saved data, and it now works. But now I won't be able to share data with my widget...does anyone know how? (I edited my post again)

Comment: I believe that to share this data, you will need to set up app groups. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/working-with/app-groups/

Comment: @jgoldberger I did setup app groups just like in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to read the data before calling this.nsUserDefaults.Synchronize();, you won't get the data.

So if you do:

```
this.nsUserDefaults = new NSUserDefaults("myGroupId", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);

// Read data:
string myValue = this.nsUserDefaults.StringForKey("myKey");
```

You won't get the data. But if you call the Synchronize() method before the read you will get the data:

```
this.nsUserDefaults = new NSUserDefaults("myGroupId", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
this.nsUserDefaults.Synchronize();

// Read data:
string myValue = this.nsUserDefaults.StringForKey("myKey");
```